# (Training + Testing) Data issue in Naive Bayes Classifier of Mahout 0.7

Tags: testing, classification, mahout

In Mahout how can we make train vectors and test vectors for Naive Bayes Classifier manually instead of use `"--randomSelectionPct"` option for split. According to my understanding I had built train vectors and test vectors manually as

```
bin/mahout seq2sparse -i TestSet0-seq -o TestSet0-vectors
bin/mahout seq2sparse -i TrainSet0-seq -o TrainSet0-vectors


/home/marvin1/hadoop-1.0.4/bin/hadoop fs -cp /user/marvin1/TestSet0-vectors/tfidf-vectors /user/marvin1/test-vectors
/home/marvin1/hadoop-1.0.4/bin/hadoop fs -cp /user/marvin1/TrainSet0-vectors/tfidf-vectors /user/marvin1/train-vectors
```

But by this accuracy is just 1%. Here data was 90-10 split manually. But when I had passed complete data(train+test) to mahout and used `"--randomSelectionPct 10`". Then it gives accuracy around 50%.
Please let me know what i had done wrong in this.

Answer (score 0):

Probably I'm too late in answering this query......but anyways here is what I have to say... 
How you are doing the split matters a lot..I had faced a similar problem when once during  training a data set, I had used a part of data which belonged to one particular class than the other (see [Overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting)). Hence try splitting the dataset using some randomized methods, and check the results. Should definitely improve.